# Proper way of styling links on other page

Tags: html, css

My main navigation bar is like this: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aortaFX/7c3krcy5/)

```
<div id="navbar">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="bio.html">Bio</a></li> 
            <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
            <li id="active"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="friends.html">Friends</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The css for it is as follow:

```
#navbar {
float: left;
height: 100px;
width: 395px;
background-color: orange;
background-color: #CCCCCC;
background-image: url(../images/1_03.jpg);
}
#navbar ul{
list-style-type: none;
margin-top: 30px;
}
#navbar li{
float: left;
text-align:center; 
width: 60px;
}
#navbar a:link, a:visited {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
font-size: 14px;
color: rgba(141,141,141,1);
text-decoration: none;
padding-top: 20px;
font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
-moz-transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
font-weight: 500;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
-o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
 transition: all 0.3s linear;
 }
#navbar a:hover, a:active {
color:white;
background-color: #ff7200;
}
#active > a {
display: block;
color: white;
background-color: rgba(51,51,51,1);
}
```

Now I have on contact page my icon images, which links to the user's profile on Facebook, Twitter, etc., but they get the same background when in active state like my navigation bar. How can I change that?

Comment: Are they also using the `#navbar` ID?

Comment: Are you icon images inside of the `<div id="navbar">`?

Comment: They will get the same style if they are in the same div. You can disable that if you do something like that #navbar a.social:active { background-color: transparent; }

Comment: no. they have no class or id http://pokit.org/get/?36fb37ddb761d9f3c95caab202b5ff18.jpg this yellow thing appears bellow them when they are pressed

Comment: Check out with firebug and look which class is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in your way of defining css :
`#navbar a:hover, a:active` should be `#navbar a:hover, #navbar a:active`

Comment: Maybe. I see so many resources, I'm so confused. I added "transparent" to it, now it's ok. But I guess I need to learn more. Thank you.